# Getting an 'Access denied' exception when trying to upload a document in a library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, access-denied

I have been working on sharepoint recently. I have created a site collection for my testing purpose, in which I have to upload documents in a library.
I used REST API and CSOM to upload the documents and it's working fine.

Now the same code I have been using on another site collection which one of collegue have created, where I have full control, but every time I tried to upload the document I am getting an error of "Access Denied. You do not have permission to perform this action."
I tried to use POSTMAN to upload the document by passing Bearer access token, still same 403 error. I used CSOM code to check if I can access the site or not, but I can access the site and print its list names or library or title name and all.
Can anyone please help me for this scenario, I'm all lost.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: I have checked the code thrice for different site collection. It's working fine. I am specifically getting error code - 2147024891.

Comment: I can share for your reference if you want.

Comment: POST /_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/<SiteName>/<Library Name>')/files/add(overwrite=true,url='test.txt') HTTP/1.1
Host: SITE.sharepoint.com
Authorization: Bearer TOKEN
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose

Comment: Try to manually upload the document in the library just to check if there is any unique permissions in it. And are you including the Request Digest Value in your header `"X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()` ??

Comment: Yes, I can add document manually. I have used this same configuration on one of my site collection and I am not facing any issue. No, I am not including RequestDigest as for postman it's not required. The problem I am facing is with the POST call only. When I am trying to get the title of site I can get it easily.

Comment: But When I am trying to upload any document using REST API, I am getting that 403 - Access denied."error": {
        "code": "-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."
        }